# USB Switch for sensitive peripherals?

Tags: kvm, switch

So I'm looking to share my camera/microphone between a PC and a Mac. In particular, I'm using Logitech C922 and an XLR microphone connected to Focusrite Scarlet Solo 3rd gen, using a Cloudlifter CL-1, which I'm only mentioning because it draws 48V phantom power from the interface.

I'd like to share this setup between a PC and a Mac, and a device that came recommended was ATEN US3342. Looking at it, this seems like a great device for connecting two computers, as well as sharing "low bandwidth" devices like keyboards, mice on printers. The cost of the device itself isn't that much of an issue, but the fact that it takes my interface and webcam, and boils it down to one USB C port worries me. I guess I'd be much happier with a device that does the exact same thing, but occupies two usb ports on the host machine, would that make more sense?

It's also very important that both systems understand there's two devices, rather than one hub.

Comment: Why would you want to use 2 of USB ports?  USB C has a lot of bandwidth it shouldn't be a problem.  You want 2 USB port buy 2 ATEN US3342, sure its over kill but it works.

Comment: I'm not sure, most of these devices 'consolidate' multiple inputs into one output, which isn't what I'm looking for. I'm looking for something that just switches output, and based off of anyone who ever wrote anything about audio gear, they'll always say usb hubs will cause issues. Essentially, ATEN is a hub, given it'll turn 2 inputs into one output. 

That being said, I've purchased it since, and seems to work fine, at least for what I use it. I don't have the tools or knowledge to scientifically measure quality, but from what I hear and see, it's all good!